# Vuex. Cannot use rootState in a getter of a module

Tags: vuex, getter

I have this in my root store

[image]

In a module I define this getter

```
selectedFermentables: (state,rootState) => {
       
            let prefs =rootState.userPreferences.brands_fermentable;
            state.fermentables.forEach((f) => {
                if (prefs.indexOf(f.brand_id)!= -1) {
                    result.push(f);
                }
            });
            return result;
        },
```

My app crashes saying

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: rootState.userPreferences is
> undefined

I tried many things without success. Help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

rootState needs to be the third argument... Even if you don't use 'state' or 'getters'

```
yourGetter: (state, getters, rootState) => {
    return rootState
}
```

Strangely, getters dont receive named arguments...